# How to open a new web page and prepopulate form fields

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it easy for people to fill out this form http://parkplanning.nps.gov/commentForm.cfm?documentID=55416 by opening it in a new window and having some of the fields pre-populated.  I don't own that form, so I can't change it - and it must be opened in the user's browser as I'm sure they check IP addresses for the submission.

I'm not sure how the best way to do this would be.  I'm guessing javascript?  Any suggestions/pointers?

Seems like I need to perform cross-site scripting.  Is that doable via frames or something?

Comment: if this is not possible, say so rather than giving me negative points.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just having the page open in a new tab or frame, then you can't do anything. As you said, you don't own the form, and can't change it. They probably don't check IP addresses for the submission, but it's not ethical to spoof, and it's extremely unethical to do any cross-site scripting.

Comment: I want to prepoulate the user's name and email address and let the user finish filling out the form.  just saving a few seconds of time. nothing unethical about that.

Comment: Your intent may not be unethical, but the implementation would be. It's like if you broke into a government building at night, just so you could hang up helpful signs for everyone. Cross-site scripting is hacking, even if it's "white hat" hacking.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like kayak does - opens multiple windows with search queries already going.

Comment: Right, but those airline/hotel/etc. websites have APIs that kayak has gotten permission or licenses to use.

Comment: I suppose I could call the nps.gov ppl and ask if they have an API.  Surprised that this type of thing isn't easier to do.  I was hoping I could just fill out the variables in the query string and have the form populated.

Comment: You can definitely contact the nps.gov people, and I hope you get a positive response, although it's a little unlikely. The query string is populated when the form is submitted (sometimes), but the query string doesn't populate the form. Also, the reason that you're getting downvoted is that messing around with other people's frontends is a basic "no-no" in the web dev world, and people are expecting you to know the basics of frontend development before asking a question on Stack Overflow. Best of luck getting this problem solved.

Comment: Thnx for the suggestions/help/info.  I still don't see why prepopulating a form is considered bad, but I'll just take it that it is.  My first job doing front end work was in '96 and this is the first I've heard of this being a no-no in 18 years of doing this type of work (on-and-off).  though I've never had to prepopulate someone else's form before..